# exceptions raised from within a urlfetch callback

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, urlfetch

When performing async `urlfetch` calls with a callback and inside a tasklet, it seems that exceptions raised from within the callback don't propagate to the wrapping tasklet.

Example code:

```
def cb() :
  raise Exception, 'just a test'

rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(callback = cb)

@ndb.tasklet
def t() :
  try :
    response = yield urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, 'http://...')
  except :
    print 'an error occured'

  raise ndb.Return

t().get_result()
```

In the code above, executed by the dev server, the "just a test" exception doesn't get caught inside the tasklet; ie. instead of the error message being output to the console i'm getting the "just a test" exception reported.

If there's a generic `urlfetch` exception related to the `make_fetch_call` (such as `DownloadError` in case of a bad URL), it's being handled properly.

Is there a way to catch callback-generated exceptions inside the tasklet in such a situation? Or maybe should this behavior be considered a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: If there is space in your URL the replace it with %20
It will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [sample project](https://github.com/dt-rush/pythonUrlFetchTest) to illustrate the correct way to do this.

While reading the code, you'll find a lot of benefit from reading the comments and also cross-referencing with the docs on [tasklets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async) and [rpc.make_fetch_call()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests).

Some of the confusing aspects of this were the fact that ndb tasklets actually use Exceptions to indicate return values (even if successful, you should `raise ndb.Return (True)`, making exception handling difficult to tiptoe around), and the fact that exceptions in the callback needs to be caught when we call `wait()` on the `rpc` future object returned by `t()`, while exceptions in the url fetch need to be caught inside `t()` itself when we do `yield rpc.make_fetch_call()`. There may be a way to do the latter using rpc.check_success(), but that'll be up to your hacking to figure out.

I hope you find the source helpful, and I hope you learned a lesson about avoiding using exceptions to indicate that a generator is done...